# How to pickle class attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, pickle

```
import pickle
import os

class Animal:
    records = dict()    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

while True:
    answer = input("-->")
    
    if answer == "add":
        name = input("name : ")
        
        new_animal = Animal(name)
        Animal.records[name] = new_animal

        with open("data.p", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(Animal.records, f)

    elif answer == "show":
        with open("data.p", "rb") as f:
            print(pickle.load(f))
```

I saved `records` with the `pickle` module. After restarting the program, if I query the `records` contents without adding new data, I can see the records, but if I add new data, I cannot see the old records. Why can't I see old records?

Comment: When you read the data back from the file, you just print it - you aren't storing it back in `Animal.records`.

Comment: Please show us what you mean with code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686398/python-pickle-module-usage/68686433#68686433

Comment: I want to adapt the solution I linked above to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the else part of your code to make it work.

```
  elif answer == "show":
        with open("data.p", "rb") as f:
            Animal.records = pickle.load(f) #reload your object
            print(Animal.records)
```